# mysql getting closest value based on 2 columns

Tags: mysql

Given an input value for N and DT.  I need to select the row with n=N and dt=DT.
If theres an exact match, its easy, but if there is no exact match, I need the 4 closest row in order to compute an interpolated value for v for my program.

```
| n | dt        | v |
| 1 | 06-08-2017| 1 |    
| 2 | 06-08-2017| 2 |
| 3 | 06-08-2017| 3 |
| 5 | 06-08-2017| 4 |
| 7 | 06-08-2017| 5 |
| 1 | 06-10-2017| 2 |
| 2 | 06-10-2017| 3 |
| 3 | 06-10-2017| 4 |
| 5 | 06-10-2017| 5 |
| 8 | 06-10-2017| 6 |
```

With the simplified table above. if there N = 6 and DT = 06-09-2017.  I need as output

```
| 5 | 06-08-2017| 4 |
| 7 | 06-08-2017| 5 |
| 5 | 06-10-2017| 5 |
| 8 | 06-10-2017| 6 |
```

If there is an exact match.  it doesn't really matter if you return 4 rows or 1 or 3 rows (for partial match).  The interpolation function is able to handle  this.

I can do it for 1 variable

```
(select * from db where n >= N order by n limit 1)
union
(select * from db where n < N order by n desc limit 1)
```

but am having a lot of difficulty doing this for both variables. I tried doing the above twice but basically u get the wrong row because only 1 variable is correct.

Any help is very much appreciated

*** EDIT ***

In the end I managed to do what I want via.

```
(select * from db from n>=N and dt = (select dt from db where dt >= DT order 
by dt limit 1) order by n limit 1)
union distinct
(select * from db from n<=N and dt = (select dt from db where dt >= DT order 
by dt limit 1) order by n desc limit 1)
union distinct
(select * from db from n>=N and dt = (select dt from db where dt <= DT order 
by dt desc limit 1) order by n limit 1)
union distinct
(select * from db from n<=N and dt = (select dt from db where dt <= DT order 
by dt desc limit 1) order by n desc limit 1)
```

Seems like there has got to be an easier way though

Answer (score 1):

When you say 'the closest' working with two values you are basically talking of the closest distance between two bi-dimensional vectors. So in order to get that working you will need to define a norm over them.

A good starting point would be a the [euclidean norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Euclidean_norm) using for the unix timestamp for the dates.

Something like this:

```
SQRT(n*n + unix_timestamp(dt)*unix_timestamp(dt))
```

then you can use that calculated norm as your value to compare instead of N.

Take in count that unix_timestamp only work with dates in the YYYY-MM-DD format.

Also you should add a coefficient for n and another for dt to normalize the values. If any of them is bigger enough than the other your norm will tend to the value of the greatest component (I'm sure your timestamps will be way bigger than you n's). So you should do something like this:

```
SQRT(a*n*n + b*unix_timestamp(dt)*unix_timestamp(dt))
```

where a and b are real values in the range of 0..1

for example

```
SQRT(0.9*n*n + 0.1*unix_timestamp(dt)*unix_timestamp(dt))
```

Play with them until your results are good enough.

---

### EDIT: Elaborating the answer

The problem you're facing is, mathematically: *Given a set S of tuples (n,dt) and a particular tuple (n',dt') where n and n' are integers and dt and dt' are dates, return the set of the M tuples of S that are at the shortest distance from (n',dt')*

Said that, you need to define your distance. You have two chances:

- Either you elaborate some kind of algorithm following the reasoning you did to select the 4 examples from your question (which I don't know)
- Or you define a mathematical distance over your set of tuples. I'm going to elaborate on this.

If you represent your tuples in a cartesian plane you will see the following:

[image: cartesian_plane]

The vertical edge represents n and the horizontal represents dt. The blue arrows represent the distance from one particular tupla to other.

Now, this distance can be defined in several ways. The most common is the Euclidean Distance which is defined by the following expression:

```
d([n,dt],[n',dt'])= sqrt( (n-n')^2 + (dt-dt')^2 )
```

Now you want all of the M results that minimize that distance, let's build a query.

Firstly you need to calculate the difference between dt and dt' which are dates. You can either give each date a scalar value or you can use some MySQL functions to directly get the difference in days. Let's go for this.

```
DATEDIFF(dt, dt')
```

Now, DATEDIFF needs DATE fields (which follow the format YYYY-MM-DD but your dates are reversed so we will need to format them to be used. Here I'll asume your fixed value dt' will be introduced correctly by hand.

```
DATEDIFF(str_to_date(date_format(dt, '%d-%m-%Y'), '%d-%m-%Y'), dt')
```

Now we have our date difference lets build the entire distance:

```
SQRT(POW((n-n'),2)+POW(DATEDIFF(str_to_date(date_format(dt, '%d-%m-%Y'), dt'), '2017-05-05'),2))
```

We can now, adjusting some variables, just create a SQL query that chooses the nearest values:

```
SELECT *, SQRT(POW((t.n-N),2)+POW(DATEDIFF(str_to_date(date_format(t.dt, '%d-%m-%Y'), '%d-%m-%Y'), DT),2)) as distance FROM TABLE_NAME t ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT M;
```

You need to replace N for your n' value, DT for your dt' value, M for the number of nearest tuples you need and TABLE_name for the name of your table.

**Some considerations**

1. As DATEDIFF returns the difference in days the value for the `(dt-dt')^2` part of the distance formula will be in general much greater than the part `(n-n')^2`. That means that the value of the distance will be composed mainly by the dates (having more decision in the distance value). If this results do not convence you, you can just add weights to your components and play with those values until you get results that are good enough for you. A query with weights would be as follows:

   `SELECT *, SQRT(A*POW((t.n-N),2)+B*POW(DATEDIFF(str_to_date(date_format(t.dt, '%d-%m-%Y'), '%d-%m-%Y'), DT),2)) as distance FROM TABLE_NAME t ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT M;`

You need to substitute A and B for your weights. I recommend values in between 0 and 1, where the sum of both is 1. I.e. [A=0.9,B=0.1]. Assigning a greater value to A will result in N having more influence in the distance value, the same with B for DT.

2. This distance is not unique. And in fact no distance is unique. For instance if you work only with the values of N. And you need to find the 4 rows that are nearer to the second one in your example table, you will find that the first and the third are 1 unit away from it. But it don't affect your problem, will it?
3. This distances can't be precomputed and stored in an efficient way. If you have X entries in your tables you will need to store the distances of each row to each of it's partners. Which means you need X-1 extra fields for each row (it would be a bad implementation any way). If you're really interested on this, you can find a way to have another table with the distance for every pair of records and executing this query using a join to that table.
4. This query uses a lot of native functions and math operations so it won't be the fastest query. In my local environment it took a little less than the double of the time needed to execute a flat SELECT.
5. There are other definitions of distance, you can investigate and use the one best fits to your problem. But the idea behind this query is still to minimize the distance no matter how you define it.

Comment: im not good at math so please correct me if im wrong.  but seems like this is not unique?  i can have 2 different (n,dt) pairs giving the same euclidean norm?  Also data base is really large, would this be very time consuming?

Comment: Thats right it's not unique. I don't know the nature of your problem but if you need "the closest" it won't affect in most cases. I would start by trying to fetch the exact record from the db (wich will be unique if at least one of the components is unique) im first place and then use the norm for thw closest 4 if theres no match. It will rise your times for sure. A work around is to precalculate (can do it in your program code if any) the norm and save it to a column for each record. It will rise your insert time but the problem of selecting will be much easier from the mysql point of view.

Comment: Regarding the uniqueness, if you work with only N you can have 2 records that are X units far from your target values. So it is not unique even for one single parameter :)

Comment: As a generalized example.  if I want n=5/dt = 1 and im expecting the call to return n=6/dt = 2 as nearest.  It would be a problem if the call returns n=2 and dt = 6.  This seems like a possibility using a precomputed norm or am i wrong somewhere?

Comment: This possibility exists with both precomputed and on-the-fly alternatives. But that can also happen with your one parameter example. If you look for n=3 and there's no match then you could have in return a n=2 when you where waiting for a n=4 (because them both are 1 unit away from n=3). Any way, I'm thinking that you can't precompute. The distance is the norm of the difference and you can store all those values efficiently. Let me get out of work and I'll elaborate a little more on the answer.

Comment: Updated my answer with a better explanation, hope it helps.

Comment: tks so much. will need to digest this. still hoping for pure sql type search solution.  but im really appreciate your effort and help